# The tornado is building with wind speeds of over 100 kilometers an hour

Tags: word-meaning, sentence-meaning

> Weather report
>
> Weatherman: A severe cold spell is forecast for northern regions this week with temperature dropping to minus 20 degrees Celsius.
> The tornado is **building** with wind speeds of over 100 kilometers an hour.

What does "**building**" mean in this sentence?

Does it mean "**developing**"?

Comment: Cite your source please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an intransitive verb, ***build*** is defined by [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/build) as

> - 1: to engage in building
> - 2a: to progress toward a peak (as of intensity); ex: build to a climax
> - 2b: to develop in extent; ex: a crowd building

So I would understand your sentence as

> The tornado is building (***increasing/growing***) with wind speeds of over 100 kilometers an hour.

Yes, ***developing*** can explain ***building*** in the given context, although I would argue that ***building*** is more commonly used with ***tornado***.

Comment: As one of the older generation, my first thought was to argue the other way as regards tornadoes ***building / developing***. But [this NGram usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+tornado+building%2Ca+tornado+developing&year_start=1960&year_end=2010&corpus=26&smoothing=10) clearly suggests you have your finger on the idiomatic pulse here. ***Building*** has been the more common verb for the past couple of decades, and all the indications are that this preference is getting stronger every year.

Comment: Yet clearly only **the development of a tornado** is used.

Comment: haha yes - *the building of tornadoes* doesn't sound at all idiomatic! I guess that's because a tornado could (intransitively) build (itself) for no particular reason (because weather). But *building tornadoes* sounds like a deliberate act that only mad scientists and overexcited rain gods would consider doing!

Comment: I guess one could _**build a tornado of bad rumours**_?